# How to redirect subdomain to a port being listened by Nodejs on Apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I almost broke my brain while figuring it out and I need some help.

I have a shared hosting, Apache 2.4, example.com and a website running on main domain built in php.

I installed nodejs and it is running on example.com:5000 and it is working well, however I need nodejs to be able to listen to the subdomain app.example.com (and app.domain.com/*)

I have tried so many combinations of following things and none worked out.

Using vhost package for nodejs:

```
    const vhost = require('vhost');
     const express = require('express');
     const app = express();
        ****
     express()
     .use(vhost('app.example.com', require('../widget/app.js').app))
     .listen(port) 
//it is only listening to the port, and doesn't work for the subdomain
```

Rewriting .**htaccess** file and saving it to the **root folder** or the **public folder** or the **app folder**:

variant 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ app.example.com/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:50000/$1 [P,L]
```

Variant 2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^50000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Variant 3:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://app.example.com:50000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.example.com:50000/$1 [P,L]
```

What is the right way to make it happened?

Have a great day!

Comment: Variant 1 looks fine (the rest does not really make sense) , but this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ app.example.com/$` has to be changed to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app\.example\.com$` (no leading blank, no trailing slash). That should work for the frontend server, the apache http server. I cannot say anything about the settings inside the nodejs server.

Comment: Thank you! which folder this htaccess file should go to? root, public or node folder? I actually changed the code in the public folder, and it didn't work and moreover, the main website also stopped working, so after I cleared the file, the website work restored, no problem..

Comment: Best location for that rule would be the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (cheapo hosting provider), then a distributed configuration file is an option, that would be a ".htaccess" file in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. If that "didn't work" you need to be more specific what that actually means. Please add a description to the question as an update.

Comment: Thank you! I actually gave up playing with .htaccess and could make nodejs listen to a port on subdomain. It will work for my purpose.

Comment: I fail to understand that comment. I previously understood that nodejs was running in parallel to apache and that you wanted to implement a proxy setup, so use apache as frontend and nodejs as backend server. But anyway, the important thing is not me understanding what you want to achieve, but that you achive your goals. So congratulations, have fun!